# Change Color of element when different element is hovered

Tags: html, css, font-awesome

I am trying to achieve on this page here - http://derbyshiregas.co.uk/ on the **HOME PAGE** within the **OUR SERVICES** section.

That when hovering over a services box both the text and the fa-icon/font awesome icon change colour on hover. I have got the text working but cannot get it working with the icon as well.

If someone could give us a little help with the CSS code I need to use for this it would be a big help.

Below is the current code I am using for the text... just cant get the fa-icon working with this.

```
    .service-nav-tab li a:hover, .service-nav-tab li.active a {
  background: linear-gradient(132deg, #e31372, #12a9c1, #5086bb, #6a10b4, #d49c10);
    background-size: 400% 400%;
      animation: BackgroundGradient 40s ease infinite;
  -webkit-background-clip: text;
  -webkit-text-fill-color: transparent;
}
```

Comment: `.service-nav-tab li a:hover .fa` ???

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to affect other elements when a div is hovered](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4502633/how-to-affect-other-elements-when-a-div-is-hovered)

Comment: thanks for the help

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It appears that the pseudo element (**FontAwesome**'s way of inserting an icon, eg: `.fa .fa-fire:before`) does not maintain the background colors that you've applied to the `a` tag.

Try adding the `background` and the `-webkit-background-clip` properties to the pseudo element itself - that has fixed it for me when playing with your css in dev tools.

```
.service-nav-tab li a:hover .fa:before {
  background: linear-gradient(132deg, #e31372, #12a9c1, #5086bb, #6a10b4, #d49c10);
  background-size: 400% 400%;
  animation: BackgroundGradient 40s ease infinite;
  -webkit-background-clip: text;
  -webkit-text-fill-color: transparent;
  -webkit-background-clip
}
```

**Edit:** I don't have an explanation for why this fixes it, or why it fails in the first place. However, I tinkered a bit more with some properties and found that breaking out of the document flow causes the same problems even for the `h4` containing your main text.

Comment: Hi, This has fixed the issue, only think I can not get working now for the .fa to be styled when active/selected. I have tried adding the .active and :after selectors but not having any luck

Comment: published you code onto the site so you can see what I mean

Comment: `.service-nav-tab li.active a .fa:before` is this the selector you tried?

Comment: Got you, I had tried this but must have not seen the affect happening. My bad. Thanks for the help

Comment: Also, just to add on... How would I be able to tie this affect to the line underneath my nav menu current item? this is coded differently

Answer (score 0):

You are including hover together with active or not showing all code of service-nav-tab.

Try this:

```
.service-nav-tab li.active a {
  background: linear-gradient(132deg, #e31372, #12a9c1, #5086bb, #6a10b4, #d49c10);
    background-size: 400% 400%;
      animation: BackgroundGradient 40s ease infinite;
  -webkit-background-clip: text;
  -webkit-text-fill-color: transparent;
}

.service-nav-tab li a:hover {
    background: linear-gradient(OTHER SET HERE);
    }
```